# How to attach mounted flat-screen TV to the wall so that it lines up perfectly?

Tags: walls, mounting, level, brackets, screens

As you can see the TV in the following pictures has been attached to the wall behind it but it does not line up in a straight manner with the furniture below it (the piece of furniture is perfectly lined up with the room's floor which is also level). In this case, the TV screen is slightly tilted upwards on right-hand side. I would like to know, what can I do to get the edges of the TV square with the furniture and room's floor?

[image]

[image]

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your mount is slightly skew. The "fix" will be determined by the fastener type used. If you used bolts, you may be able to adjust left or right.

Comment: Take the plastic cover (the curved white plastic) off and look under it, and/or post a picture.

Answer (score 2):

The adjustment is usually under on the wall part of the bracket. The bracket needs to be plumb in both planes (kind of left and right and then forward and backward).

The better brackets are bolted back to the wall and then micro adjusted (via small adjustment grub screws) in all planes until absolutely spot on. Then assuming no play in the arm, all should be well.

Have seen a few that are very difficult to get right in all planes though. I.e, TV looks good pushed back but wrong when pulled out etc.

Using serrated spring washers helps hold the bracket firm if the problem is caused by bolt heads slipping in bracket slots.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an adjustment screw to counter the gravity on the articulated arm. The silver screw in the picture closest to the back of the TV comes to mind as being an adjustment, but then again, you may need to slip the covers off the bracket on the wall, loosen them up a turn, tilt the bracket the other way and tighten the screws back up. The down side to this is when you swing the arm the other way, it will REALLY out of level.

Comment: This answer is based on using the arm you already have. There are mounts that will not sag IF you need the swing arm feature. If you don't there many tilting or solid wall mounts that will keep it level as you ask.